# $scope.$watch can not watch some values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd faced an issue related to $scope.$watch. Here is my code snippet.

```
$scope.$watch('vm.pageData.wti.price', function(value) {
   filterWatcher.setWtiPrice(value); 
}
```

vm.pageData.wti.price has price data, like $30.00

When executed code, I got this error:

> Syntax Error: Token '.00' is an unexpected token at column 4 of the
>   expression [$30.00] starting at [.00].

It seems the value "$30.00" inside the variable "vm.pageData.wti.price" caused this error. Is it impossible to watch the data of this kind?

Comment: It's just a string, so the answer is yes. Need more detail about where that error is generated (in the `filterWatcher.setWtiPrice` I imagine) & what happens to `value` inside that method.

Comment: @RandyCasburn - Thanks for your response. filterWatcher.setWtiPrice is simple service for saving data. Is it impossible to watch string data?
I found the error was occured in the $scope.$watch line.

Comment: You aren't watching string data, you are watching a property and it's value. A string is a valid property value and can be watched. The error you posted indicates the data is being parsed or corerrced into a different data type somewhere. But if you don't want share I can't help.

Comment: Thanks for your kind attention. But I don't think so. It's ridiculously.
The error is occurring here : b.$watch (http://localhost:8001/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js:141:377

Answer (score 0):

add a true argument after the function, this will watch an object inside the object

```
$scope.$watch('vm.pageData.wti.price', function(value) {
   filterWatcher.setWtiPrice(value); 
}, true);
```

Comment: Oh Sorry - I think this is not a true solution.